# Computational Complexity of Algorithm in Big Oh, Big Omega and Theta

Tags: matrix, complexity-theory

I am trying to solve the following question on computational complexity:

> Compute the computational complexity of the following algorithm and
>   write down its complexity in Big O, Big Omega and Theta
>
> ```
> for i=1 to m {
>    x(i) =0;
>    for j=1 to n {
>       x(i) = x(i) + A(i,j) * b(j)
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> where A is mxn and b is nx1.

I ended up with Big O `O(mn^2)`
Big `Omega(1)` and `Theta(mn^2)`.

Comment: Looking at the structure of the code, I would say *O(m n)* as well as *Omage(m n)* and *Theta(m n)*...

Comment: Yes, but Omega(1) is extremely loose. Every algorithm runs in Omega(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the following statement runs in constant time:

```
    x(i) = x(i) + A(i,j) * b(j)
```

this is thus done in *O(1)*, and does not depend on the values for `i` and `j`. Since you iterate over this statement in the inner `for` loop, exactly `n` times, you can say that the following code runs in *O(n)*:

```
x(i) =0;
for j=1 to n {
    meth1
}
```

(assuming the assignment is done in constant time as well). Again it does not depend on the exact value for `i`. Finally we take the outer loop into account:

```
for i=1 to m {
   meth2
}
```

The method `meth2` is repeated exactly `m` times, thus a tight upper bound for the time complexity in *O(n m)*.

Since there are no conditional statements, nor recursive and the structure of the data *A*, *b* and *x* does not change the execution of the program, the algorithm is also *big Omega(m n)* and *big Theta(m n)*.

Of course you can over-estimate big oh and under-estimate big omega: for every algorithm you can say it is *Ω(1)* and for some that it is *O(2<sup>n</sup>)*, but the point is that you do not buy much with that.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that `f = Theta(g)` if and only if `f=O(g)` and `f=Omega(g)`.

The matrix-vector product can be computed in `Theta(mn)` time (assuming naive implementation) and the sum of vectors in `O(m)`, so the total running time is `Theta(mn)`. From here it follows that the time is also `O(mn)` and `Omega(mn)`.